# How do I stop safari from displaying power use warning?

Tags: safari

I have simple dashboard visualization in d3 shown in Safari running on a MacMini on a big screen in fullscreen. https://tovare.com/dashboard/

- After a while a grey line is shown in the top of the screen with a message that the page uses a lot of power.and if I close it could make the Mac faster.
- When I close the alert, it shows up again.

Does anyone know where I can find the configuration option to remove it?

(Safari version 11.1 on both systems)

Comment: Can you provide a screen shot of the popup?  I can't replicate.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I'm aware there is no way to stop this.

In earlier versions of Safari, disabling plugins would also disable how it managed its power usage, but:

- It's unclear whether disabling plugins in newer versions still has this affect
- I'm not sure doing this would necessarily stop the warnings themselves
- It also means disabling any other plugins you may *want* to use

Regardless, if you'd like to give this a go:

1. Launch Safari
2. Press <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>,</kbd> (or just go to **Safari > Preferences...**)
3. Select the **Advanced** tab
4. Untick the *Internet plug-ins* checkbox
5. Exit preferences

Answer (score 0):

I used https://desktop.appmaker.xyz/ to wrap my visualization into a chrome based application and run it in fullscreen, which seems to work fine and it seems to stay in fullscreen :-)